# Kafka relationship with Zookeeper

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

As I know, zookeeper stores metadata about kafka mainly dealing with leadership election, partitioning details, etc.

But when I remove `/tmp/kafka-logs` directory, and restarted kafka again, it got the data again in the `/tmp/kafka-logs` directory.

Is it possible that zookeeper is also holding the data, and pass it to kafka to synchronize it?

I am using the current latest version of kafka which is 1.0.1

Comment: The version of Kafka is also important - recent versions of the Kafka broker have less reliance on ZK.

Comment: Looks like the question is not related to Spring at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zookeeper is used to store the information about the topics, partitioning etc. But not the records / messages it self. So when you delete the `kafka-logs` directory and restart Kafka, it will recover the *metadata* and recreate the topics, partitions etc. But the records cannot be recovered from Zookeeper.

If you used replication and did this only for a single broker, the records should be recovered from other replicas of the same partition. But without replication (or when you delete it for all brokers) the records / messages will be lost.